# After Installing new Extension getting Error: There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento-1.9, error, extensions

I have just installed the new Extension to the site but suddenly i got the following errors.

**There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1450658978192**

I tried a method by creating tmp folder at the root and set the permission to 775 and and changed the cache folder to the created one but still the error remains there.

Please help:

HERE IS THE ERROR LOG:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:168:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.manv_testimonials' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `manv_testimonials` AS `main_table`";i:1;s:5532:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
4 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
5 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
6 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
7 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
8 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
9 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(522): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
10 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(569): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
11 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
12 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Manv/Testimonials/Block/Adminhtml/Testimonials/Grid.php(19): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
13 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Manv_Testimonials_Block_Adminhtml_Testimonials_Grid->_prepareCollection()
14 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
15 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
16 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
17 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
18 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
19 /var/www/html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
20 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/m...')
21 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
22 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
23 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
24 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
25 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
26 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
27 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
28 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
29 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
30 /var/www/html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
31 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/m...')
32 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
33 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
34 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
35 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
36 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
37 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
38 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Manv/Testimonials/controllers/Adminhtml/TestimonialsController.php(16): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
39 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Manv_Testimonials_Adminhtml_TestimonialsController->indexAction()
40 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
41 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
42 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
43 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
44 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
45 {main}";s:3:"url";s:47:"/index.php/testimonials/adminhtml_testimonials/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: go to `var/report /1450658978192` and check the error and add that too in question.

Comment: Updated the Question @QaisarSatti Satti

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `manv_testimonials` this table manually. go to

`app/code/local or community/Manv/Testimonials/sql/testimonials_setup/here the file have sql  script`

run that script..